# OctoPrint won't stop my print with a pause

Tags: g-code, octoprint, bigtreetech

Using the PrusaSlicer I discovered that we are able to [insert a pause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSdqP.png) in mid print.

I wanted to use such feature to insert a lens in my print so I don't have to glue 2 parts to make my magnifying glass.

But unfortunately the print didn't stop at the specified layer.
Trying to manually pause the printer from the LCD didn't worked either.

The only way to stop my print is to print from the SD card instead of using OctoPrint.

Is there a pre-requisite to be able to trigger a pause from the G-code using OctoPrint?

Apparently PrusaSlicer insert an `M601` command, maybe this had to be somewhat changed to another G-code command?

My 3D printer is an Ender 3 with an alternative 32-bit board : [BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3 V1.2](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/blob/master/firmware/V1.2/Marlin-2.0.x-SKR-Mini-E3-V1.2/Marlin/Configuration_adv.h)

I'm using the stock firmware : `firmware-bltouch-for-z-homing.bin`

I tried to look into the `Configuration.h` to see if there was a pause feature to enable but I didn't see it.

I've tried to pause, it didn't even trigger automatically when printing from the SD card... Maybe I need to tell the slicer to issue another G-code that is not `M601`...

Comment: Are you able to edit in codes like M4, G25, or M226? Are you able to insert a very slow move to home at the end of the layer, giving you time to place your lens?

Comment: I don't manually edit the code, I was hopping to set the slicer in such way so I don't have to hack into the file.
I'm not familiar with M4 nor M226, I'll give them a try

Comment: @Davo You probably mean `G4` not `M4` and `M25` and not `G25` ;-) Note that `M25` should work for pausing SD prints. A safe way to pause a print is to insert a dwell time with `G4`.

Comment: Pausing has been asked before, there are multiple solutions posted. Note that it also depends on the version and configuration of the firmware.

Comment: I've tried to "insert custom GCODE" M25 in the slicer, the print paused nicely, the LCD showed me "print paused" message and I could then place my part to be embedded into my print, but then impossible to resume the print. I've waisted enough PLA today, I'll glue the parts with super glue... I think pausing prints aren't compatible with OctoPrint / my board / my printer or whatever. Thanks you all for helping me

Comment: @Sandra Clicking the/a button on the display didn't resume it?

Comment: Sadly no, I selected "resume print" from the LCD and the printer stay paused.

Comment: I think you are running Marlin Frimware 1.1.x, this means that you could use [`M600`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M600:_Filament_change_pause).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pause at the Octoprint command streaming level rather than at the printer level, have your slicer emit the Octoprint `@pause` command rather than real gcode for pause. This will cause it to go into the paused state and not send any further commands until you hit resume.

Comment: Docs link https://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/features/atcommands.html 
Supported from octoprint version 1.3.7